# invalid grouping factor specification in lmer model

Tags: r, lmer

I am attempting to run a mixed effects model using the lmer function. My experiment included metabolic rates at different temperatures using some of the same individuals (some missing data). The structure of the textfile looks like this:

```
> str(data.by.animal)
'data.frame':   18 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ animal: Factor w/ 18 levels "08_03","08_07",..: 17 6 5 10 15 14 11 12 16 9 ...
 $ temp  : int  2 0 -2 -4 -6 -8 -10 -12 -14 -16 ...
 $ X2    : num  0.0129 0.0176 0.0132 NA 0.0144 0.0133 0.0101
```

When I run the script `[model_1 <- lmer(X2 + X0 + X.2 + X.4 + X.6 + X.8 + X.10 + X.12 + X.14 + X.16 + X.18 + X.20 + X.22 + X.24 + X.26 ~ temp + (1 | animal), data.by.animal)]` I get the following: `[Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : Invalid grouping factor specification, animal]` and despite consulting "The R Book" and other answers here, I'm still at a loss as to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this model specification doesn't make any sense to me, if that's really what you used.  `lmer` requires a *single* response variable on the left-hand side of the `~` ... is this really what you tried?

Comment: comment to @dhd, whose question/comment posted as an answer was deleted.  You could post this as a new question.  The only thing I can see that looks suspicious in your formulation or data set is that all the values of `time2` that we can see are `NA` ... when you re-post, can you also show the results of `summary()` (which will count the number of `NA`s)?   Or the structure of `droplevels(na.omit(test))` ?

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered with this problem when using lmer. When I check my data, I found values of several variables were NA (resulted from rescaling). After excluding those variables, the problem was solved.

Comment: This applies to me too...
Note the NA can be in fixed effect variables in addition to random effect factors.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment, this model specification doesn't make sense -- `lmer` requires a single response variable on the left-hand side of the `~`.  It's not tested for, because it's not a mistake we thought of anyone making ... (What were you trying to do ?? Did you want to run separate analyses for each of the `X*` variables?)

I can more or less reproduce this, as long as one of the elements on the left-hand side is a factor ...

```
library(lme4)
```

This does *something*, but I'm not sure what ...

```
lmer(Reaction + Days ~ (1| Subject), sleepstudy)
```

it's close to `lmer(Reaction ~ (1|Subject), sleepstudy)` (which I might have expected -- silently ignoring the second term on the LHS?), but not identical ...

Factors on the LHS are allowed, although they don't make much sense (they're probably just being converted to numeric):

```
lmer(factor(Days) ~ (1| Subject), sleepstudy)
```

If I put them both in I can get the error:

```
lmer(Reaction + factor(Days) ~ (1| Subject), sleepstudy)
## Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
##   Invalid grouping factor specification, Subject
## In addition: Warning message:
## In Ops.factor(Reaction, factor(Days)) : + not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Unless OP has withheld information about how the X.is are coded, there is no factor on the LHS for the formula. While the error is the same, we need to know if the X.is are factors before we can be sure that's the problem here.

For whatever reason, R will interpret the addition of variables on the LHS of a formula object as a single sum. Try this with a simple lm object, you'll find that I(y1 + y2) ~ x1 gives the same output as y1 + y2 ~ x1. 

Contrast with addition of variables on the RHS, and R parses them out into unique columns of the design matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, this is correct. You want to fit a random intercepts model with a random effects for animal. You have 18 observations and animal is a factor with 17 levels, so basically there is only at most 1 repeated measure. Mixed models won't converge in those kinds of circumstances. I urge you to rethink the analysis you have here.

As far as the error, the lme4 package source throws the error here:

```
    ## convert grouping variables to factors as necessary
    for (i in all.vars(x[[3]])) {
        frloc[[i]] <- factor(frloc[[i]])
    }
    ff <- eval(substitute(factor(fac), list(fac = x[[3]])), frloc)
    if (all(is.na(ff)))
        stop("Invalid grouping factor specification, ",
             deparse(x[[3]]))
```

you might want to consider how `animal` is coded. Try recoding to some other value.

Can you print the output of `traceback()` after your shell throws the error?